# Как повторить цикл отсчета таймера?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Не могу придумать, как лучше реализовать повторение цикла таймера тренировки. По умолчанию цикл один. 
список упражнений

```
let exersiseName = ["БЕГ", "ПРЫЖКИ", "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ"]
@IBOutlet var nameExersiseLabel = UILabel()//лэйбл с названием упражнения
@IBOutlet var timerLabel = UILabel()//лэйбл секундомера

var timer = NSTimer()
var exersiseTime = 30
var timerRunning = false
var i = 0
var sets = 2 //вводим переменную количества циклов которая будет меняться 
// КАК ЕЕ ПРИМЕНИТЬ ДЛЯ ПОВТОРЕНИЯ ПОКАЗА НАЗВАНИЙ УПРАЖНЕНИЙ И ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЯ РАБОТЫ ТАЙМЕРА ДО ОКОНЧАНИЯ ВТОРОГО ЦИКЛА
func Counting(){
    exersiseTime -= 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(Int(exersiseTime))"
    if exersiseTime == -1 {
        i += 1
        exersiseTime = 30
        timerLabel.text = "\(Int(exersiseTime))"
    } 
    if i + 1 < exersiseName.count { //Ход тренировки
            nameExersiseLabel.text = exersiseName[i] as? String
    } else if i + 1 == exersiseName.count { //Последнее упражнение в тренировке
            nameExersiseLabel.text = exersiseName[i] as? String
    } else if i + 1 > exersiseName.count { //Конец тренировки
            timerLabel.text = "0"
            timer.invalidate()
            timerRunning = false
    }
}
```

Кнопку старта таймера не пишу, если кому-то надо, то добавлю

Comment: не очень понятный вопрос - как сделали первый таймер, так же делайте и повторения.

Answer (score 1):

Есть решение!

Объявляем еще одну переменную `var count = 0`, ставим условие `if i + 1 > exersiseName.count` первым и модифицируем следующим образом:

```
if i + 1 > exersiseName.count { //Конец цикла
    count+=1
    if (count >= sets) {
         timerLabel.text = "0"
         timer.invalidate()
         timerRunning = false
    }else{
         i = 0
    } 
} //важно: не надо ставить здесь else
if ....
```

Comment: вы б хоть код отформатировали